# Access a class of variables in another Script

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the script of my GameObject called GameController I have the following class:

```c#
[System.Serializable]
public class Spawn
{
    public bool Enemy1;
    public bool Enemy2;    
}
```

I have tried the following code:

```c#
private void TurnOff()
{
    var spawnP = gameController.GetComponent<GameController>().spawn;
    var Type = spawnP.GetType();
    var properties = Type.GetProperties();

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        properties[i].SetValue(null, false, null);
    }
}
```

My plan was that I get the properties and set them all to true or false, but nothing happens.

Comment: I suggest you post the GameController class and show the instance of Spawn, that would be helpful if the duplicate doesn't really help you.

Comment: Just take an `Spawn spawn` and do `spawn.Enemy1 = false;` Also, are you planning on using a huge list of `bool`s to tell which enemy it is? That's a horrible idea. Just use an `enum`, at least, or, better yet, child scripts/classes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the data in this class you can do:

public TheClassYouwannaAccess myclass;

And in Unity drag and drop the script/gameobject in the Variable you created.

Comment: No! This works only for classes that are "Components" derived from MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObjects.